# How to define a group structure on equivalence classes?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading Lang's Algebra and there is something I am confused about. Suppose we have a commutative monoid $M$ with the cancellation law. Now consider $M \times M.$ Define addition component wise. Say that $(x, y)$ is equivalent to $(x', y')$ if $y + x' = x + y'.$ This is an equivalence relation.

Now define a mapping $x \mapsto \text{class of } (0, x) = [(0, x)].$ Professor Lang says that this is an injective homomorphism into a group. My question is, how exactly do we define the group structure of equivalence classes? My thought is $[(a, b)] + [(c, d)] = [(a + c, b + d)].$ Clearly this group has an identity: $[(0, 0)].$ Clearly it has inverses as the negative of $(a, b)$ is $(b, a).$ It is also obviously closed. Is this the correct way of thinking about this? This also would obviously make the mapping a homomorphism.

Comment: Just a note: in Lang's book the Grothendieck group is constructed as a quotient of some free abelian group. However, the Grothendieck group can also be constructed in a similar way as described in the question, without assuming cancellation law in $M$. To achieve this, we take the equivalence to be "there exists some $z\in M$ such that $y+x'+z=x+y'+z$" instead. This treatment makes the "if and only if" proposition in the book more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: $\bigl[(a,b)\bigr]+\bigl[(c,d)\bigr]=\bigl[(a+c,b+d)\bigr]$. And, yes, $\bigl[(0,0)\bigr]$ is the identity and the inverse of $\bigl[(a,b)\bigr]$ is $\bigl[(b,a)\bigr]$. I don't think that you need to state explicitly that it is closed; this is so obvious in this case.

On the other hand, it would be a good idea to assert that $+$ is associative. And, above all, to prove that this operation does not depend upon the choices of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ within their classes of equivalence. In other words, to prove that$$(a,b)\sim (a',b')\text{ and }(c,d)\sim(c',d')\Longrightarrow(a+c,b+d)\sim(a'+c',b'+d').$$This is easy to check, of course.